# difference in the way nsmangedobjectcontext is retrieved

Tags: ios, core-data

What is the difference between the global nsmanagedobjectcontext retrieved from appdelegate and the nsmanagedobjectcontext retrieved from nsmanagedobject

1)

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

2)

```
NSManagedObject *employee1 = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = employee1.managedObjectContext;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` from your app delegate, it's whatever instance you create in your app delegate, configured in whatever way you have configured it.

If you ask a managed object for the value of its `managedObjectContext` property, you get whatever context was used to create it or fetch it.

These might be the same or they might not be, depending on how many instances of `NSManagedObject` you have created and how you are using them.